# Picking which Python XCode runs scripts on

Tags: python, xcode

I have an xcode project which runs some python scripts during the build process. They use some python packages (beautifulsoup and slimit). I am setting the project up on a new computer, and used homebrew to install python, and then pip to install the two packages.

Unfortunately, when building the project I am getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/supersloth/Code/projectname/tools/mergehtml.py", line 7, in <module>
    import slimit
ImportError: No module named slimit
```

For a while this was confusing because I know slimit is there. During my research I realized that my computer has two versions of python on it

```
Io:~ supersloth$ /usr/local/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.9
Io:~ supersloth$ /usr/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.6
Io:~ supersloth$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
Io:~ supersloth$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Io:~ supersloth$
```

and these two versions have different packages installed

default python (/usr/local)

```
['beautifulsoup4==4.3.2', 'pip==6.0.8', 'ply==3.4', 'setuptools==14.3', 'slimit==0.8.1']
```

and the second installation doesn't have either (no pip to get list of packages from, no slimit when trying to import by hand)

```
 >>> import slimit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named slimit
>>> import pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pip
>>>
```

this leads me to believe that xcode is trying to use python 2.7.6 without the packages as the default for building during xcode.

how would i change this default, in order to verify this?

Comment: i went in and installed pip, slimit, and beautifulsoup4 for the older python, did a build, and the xcode project compiled fine, so the version of python was indeed the problem. however, i am not sure how to _change_ the version that xcode uses, which would be great if someone knows the answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to force it.

```
#! path_to_desired_version
```

as the first line of each python file.

Also, if you encounter something like this again,

```
which -a python
```

will show alternatives that you have. Without the '-a', you will see which one is first in your path.